# Domain whitelisting Messenger

Tags: curl, facebook-messenger, messenger

I am trying to whitelist some domain for a Messenger bot I'm building but the command does not seem to work. It works only occasionally and I can't add more than one domain. The domain they have on their documentation always work by contrast and so does the DELETE command. Am I doing something wrong? This is the command I have:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "whitelisted_domains":[
    "https://linkedin.com”,
    "https://marcogreselin.com”,
    "https://github.com”,
    "https://instagram.com” 
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Obviously I replace the access token.

Comment: it seems you use straight quotes (`"`) and curly quotes (`”`), not sure if that's the issue

Comment: thanks that solved it